# Is there a rule of thumb when it comes to picking piece wise linear (e.g. ReLu) or non linear (e.g. sigmoid) activation functions?

Tags: neural-networks

I built a simple three layer network that takes 2 inputs and spits 3 outputs. I picked a photo, and trained this network to learn a (pixel position) --> (pixel RGB value) representation.

When I used ReLu, the network quickly converged to a 0 everywhere function. When I used sigmoid activation, the network converged to my photo without an issue.

I tried different configurations, and this behavior was consistent. It boggles me that this application preferred the non-linearity of the sigmoid function.

In cases like this, are there rules of thumb guiding the choice of the activation function?

Comment: What format your RGB values were in?

Comment: ReLU is nonlinear.

Comment: @jkm In the range 0..1

Comment: @Dave You are right; I should have said 'piece-wise' linear.